# What’s the correct nusach Ari

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, shacharis-morning-prayer, nuschaot, nusach-ari

BH

How come there are so many Nusach Ari’s?? What is the correct one to Daven from? And are all Nusach Ari’s the thirteenth gate where everyone could enter?

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2089176/jewish/The-Chassidic-Prayerbook.htm

Comment: "_How come there are so many Nusach Ari’s?? What is the correct one to Daven from?_" From Wikipedia's "[Nusach Ari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusach_Ari)": "_Nusach Ari_ means, in a general sense, **any** prayer rite following the usages of Rabbi Isaac Luria, the AriZal, in the 16th century" (Bold emphasis mine).

Comment: "_And are all Nusach Ari’s the thirteenth gate where everyone could enter?_" I'm not sure about that, but the Sephardic Halacha Yomit site's [Prayer Texts](https://halachayomit.co.il/en/ReadHalacha.aspx?HalachaID=2314) says: "... _Maran Ha’Chida writes that the Ari z”l himself who was Ashkenazi_ ... _would pray according to the Sephardic prayer text all year round besides for the High Holidays, as he writes in his Sha’ar Ha’Kavanot. Maran Ha’Chida adds that the **Sephardic prayer text ascends through all twelve gates in Heaven**_."

Comment: There is a teshuvas Chasam Sofer (www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer%2C_Orach_Chayim.15.20?lang=bi) who says that his Rebbi R' Noson Adler (and his rebbi the Hafla'ah) testified that "כל הנוסחאות שוות זו כזו". And that the Arizal used nusach Sefard because he was brought up there, but that nusach Ashkenaz contains the same deep wisdom and power ("ואילו היה נמצא באשכנזי איש כמוהו היה עושה כיוצא בזה בסידור אשכנזי"). R' Adler changed to nusach Sefard so that he could use the kavanos of the Ari, but wouldn't allow his students to change since they weren't holding by that.

Comment: There's also a dozen nusach ashkenazes. And a dozen sefardi rites too.